# multiple values for data-toggle attribute w/bootstrap ui

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to assign the data attribute data-toggle used in Bootstrap two values like:

```
echo "<td><a class='one glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='delete-row' data-toggle='modal tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Delete Record' href='#' data-target='#myModal' aria-hidden='true' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'></a></td>";
```

cause this element has a tooltip and is also used to trigger a modal when clicked. However I cant get this to work. Does anyone know if this can be done and how because I see no documentation and I've tried several different scenarios all no good.

Comment: don't use data-toggle for tooltip, just try it with using js like: `$('#element').tooltip('show')` may be this might work? :)

Comment: If I do that I don't get the Bootstrap UI styling for the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to surround your icon with a button and then style the button to be invisible.  This way you can use data-toggle on your button to call on your modal, and data-toggle on your icon to call on your tooltip.

```
<button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a class='one glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='delete-row' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Delete Record' href='#' aria-hidden='true' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'></a></button>
```

check out this link http://jsfiddle.net/jaketaylor/g0w2ztp7/ to see all of the html with the css in a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did it for me:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".delete-row").tooltip();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping it with a button you can also wrap it with a div tag add the style display inline-block on the element then add the data tags to that div.

```
echo "<td><div style='display: inline-block' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='Delete Record'><a class='one glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id='delete-row' data-toggle='modal' href='#' data-target='#myModal' aria-hidden='true' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'></a></div></td>";
```